# How to decide what view to display based on global variable

Tags: swift, xcode, navigation

I'm trying to implement an IOS swift app which starts off with a tab bar controller, and in one of the tab bar controllers is an item called "account".

When a user presses the account item, I want the app to decide (onclick event) whether the view that contains sign up/login is displayed or  the profile view is displayed based on a global variable "loggedIn" (bool type).

(I've tried navigation controller but what I've understood from that is that it is a sequence of views which can't decide between views)

I want to know how can this be implemented, maybe some kind of "router" if you may that can switch between views...

If you didn't understand here's a picture of what I'm trying to implement

[Basic Map of what I'm trying to explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93RWR.jpg)

If you can suggest a more professional way of doing such design please don't hesitate to express your opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe a good approach is updating the view controller when `loggedIn` status changes. If you don't already have, create a class inheriting from `UITabBarController` to manage your tabs. Here's the code:

```
class TabController: UITabBarController {}
```

In your storyboard, select your tab controller, go to the `Identity Inspector` and set `TabController` as the custom class. Now `TabController` will manage all the view controllers in your tab bar.

It's usually not a good approach to use global variables, so let's add `loggedIn` in the scope of `TabController` and listen for any of changes in it and update the corresponding view controller:

```
class TabController: UITabBarController {
  var loggedIn = true {
    didSet {
      updateProfileTab()
    }
  }
}
```

Now, whenever you change `loggedIn`, that change will update the proper tab. Now let's write `updateProfileTab()`:

```
class TabController: UITabBarController {
  func updateProfileTab() {
    let viewController: UIViewController
    if loggedIn {
      viewController = makeProfileViewController()
    } else {
      viewController = makeLoginViewController()
    }
    setViewController(viewController, at: 2)
  }

  func makeProfileViewController() -> ProfileViewController {
    // create and return the profile view controller
  }

  func makeLoginViewController() -> LoginViewController {
    // create and return the profile view controller
  }
}
```

Naturally, you might want to write the body of both `makeProfileViewController` and `makeLoginViewController` methods. The last thing for `TabController` is to write `setViewController(_:at:)` method:

```
class TabController: UITabBarController {
  ...
  func setViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, at index: Int) {
    let tabBarItem = viewControllers?[index].tabBarItem
    viewController.tabBarItem = tabBarItem
    viewControllers?[index] = viewController
  }
  ...
}
```

Now, since `TabController` manages your tab bar, you can access it from within any of its children view controllers:

```
guard let tabController = tabBarController as? TabController else { return }
tabController.loggedIn = ...
```

Also, it's important to select the initial state. So, in the `viewDidLoad` from one of your tabbed view controllers, you should perform the above code. The first tab (the one that displays first) is probably the best place to do that. Hope this helps!

**EDIT**

To create your login and signup view controllers, the easiest way to go is by assigning ids in your storyboard. To do that, go to your storyboard, select the view controller, and in the `Identity Inspector` set a `Storyboard ID`, which you will use to instantiate the view controller:

```
func makeProfileViewController() -> ProfileViewController {
    let controller = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "theStoryboardID")
    return controller as! ProfileViewController
}
```

Note that I'm using force unwrap here (`!`). That's just for brevity. In a real case scenario you will want to use some `if let` or `guard let` statements to handle `nil` values.

Comment: oh wow its actually more complex than i thought, I'll try to implement it like you said and i'll give it a go... just a question, the login/signup and profile views are made using the storyboard or programmatically? thanks for the reply btw, appreciate it :D

Comment: can't I leave the ProfileViewController/LoginViewController as UIViewController and return it normally without casting? Or is there a reason to create those classes and return them?

Comment: Sure you can ;D

Comment: Alright. Another question if you dont mind, should the views in storyboard(Login/profile) have some sort of relation to the tab controller at index 2 or can they be standalone views?

Comment: @Crashie No, they don't need to be related. They can be completely independent from the tab controller. One may argue that you could set one of them as the default for the tab controller. For instance, you could set the login view controller to be root view controller of the second tab bar item. It's fine if you do that way as well, but it would also be unnecessary, since you're setting the view controllers programmatically.

Comment: is there any way i can contact you some other way maybe telegram if you have, I've done everything you said and it's not working :/ (@Crashie)